# Evaluating $\int_0^l (lx-x^2)\sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{l}\right)\,\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I am stuck on evaluating the following definite integral:

$$\int_0^l (lx-x^2)\sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{l}\right) \, \mathrm{d}x$$

Aprreciate any help!

Comment: Use Integration by parts https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

$$\int P(t)\sin t\,dt=-P(t)\cos t+\int P'(t)\cos t\,dt=-P(t)\cos t+ P'(t)\sin t\,dt-\int P''(t)\cos t\,dt.$$

Also notice that $P$ and the sine vanish at the bounds, so that only the last term remains.